# One Table and several divs position

Tags: html, position, html-table

Have table and several div elements.
Table is time grid and divs are events that may take every position relatively table from top to bottom, dependently on time.

See screenshot: [alt text http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/4348/margintop.png](http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/4348/margintop.png)

So to make margin-top for div correct I specify it as negative, because these divs are positioned relatively to the table.

But in some cases they positioned relatively each other and murkup is non-correct.

So how to do these divs positions to be relative  to start point of screen and table to be as background, e.g. to specify “very” hegative z-index.

So, the question is how to do that table doesn’t affect position of divs.

Note: absolute position for divs is not acceptable, because while scrolling the table is scrolled and div is frozen.

Simplified example of HTML (in order)
table:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; width: 100%;">
</table>
```

div:

```
<div style="height: 118px; margin-left: 38px; margin-top: -94px; width: 48%;"></div>
```

Comment: Is your time grid a 1 column x N row layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely position the div relatively.

What this involves is setting position:relative on the table, you can then set position:absolute on the contained divs, these will then scroll with table, and is a more reliable way of setting the divs location and will work better across browsers.

EDIT: 
Once you have set position: absolute, you want to use top: and left: not margin-top: and margin-left: as you are not using these for their purpose.

Comment: You may also want to consider using the left and top CSS options instead of adjusting the margin as adjusting the margin will affect other elements as well.

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to mention this, once you have set position: absolute, you want to use top: and left: not margin-top: and margin-left: as you are not using these for their purpose.

Comment: If to set relative for table and absolute for divs,that they will be frozen and table will be scrolled.

Comment: No that's not true. Set overflow: auto on the table, bound it into a small space, and then set position absolute for the divs. 
As long as the divs are within the table in the DOM they will behave as you want them to.